# Retrieve particular column value using procedure in pl/sql

Tags: select, plsql, procedure

am writing procedure in pl/sql.  when i run the procedure am getting error.Here i enclosed the procedure.

```
code

PROCEDURE get_CDR_rs_phone (CDR_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)AS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN CDR_recordset FOR
   SELECT  zkv.CISCOCUIC_TBL.FLD_callingPartyNumber FROM  zkv.CISCOCUIC_TBL; 

END get_CDR_rs_phone;
/

getting error when i run this proc
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Is this procedure is in a package?

Comment: @ Poippan NO its not a package

Comment: So from where are you calling? From sqlplus or from Toad or SQL Developer?

Comment: @Polppan getting error like "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

Comment: @polppan am writing this proc in oracle toad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your procedure as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_cdr_rs_phone (
    cdr_recordset    OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN cdr_recordset FOR
        SELECT  zkv.ciscocuic_tbl.fld_callingpartynumber
          FROM  zkv.ciscocuic_tbl;
END get_cdr_rs_phone;
/
```

and execute your procedure

```
variable r refcursor;

DECLARE

BEGIN

  get_cdr_rs_phone (:r);  
END;
/

print r
```

Update 1

If your procedure is doing only a select you could do this using a function which return sys_refcursor and the function can be executed from a sql statement.

Create function as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cdr_rs_phone_func
    RETURN sys_refcursor
AS
    out_cursor   sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
          SELECT    zkv.ciscocuic_tbl.fld_callingpartynumber
              FROM  zkv.ciscocuic_tbl;
    END get_cdr_rs_phone;

    RETURN out_cursor;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        --raise error

    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        --raise error

END get_cdr_rs_phone_func;
/
```

and call this function as

```
select get_cdr_rs_phone_func from dual;
```

Comment: @ polppan wait i ll check it out and reply to u

Comment: am getting error when i create the proc like"8/14    PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
7/9     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
"

Comment: @vps How did you create your procedure? edit your question and paste the code.

Comment: i create the proc as like  i mentioned  in the question above. when i press ctrl+enter getting error, create the proce in oracle toad

Comment: @vps Do you have this part in the code? `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`

Comment: @ polppan zkv is schema name and ciscocuic_tbl is name of the table

Comment: @vps  let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19754/discussion-between-polppan-and-vps)